# ORA-00905: missing keyword after creating table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am working on sql developer (11g) , I'm trying to create this table, but it doesn't work, it says ORA-00905: missing keyword

SQL Code

```
CREATE TABLE module(
    code_mod int NOT NULL,
    intitule varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
    charge_hor int NOT NULL,
    coef double NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_module   PRIMARY KEY(code_mod) 
);
```

Comment: There is no `double` type in Oracle, use `number`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`double` is not a type in Oracle.  Use `double precision`:

```
CREATE TABLE module (
    code_mod int NOT NULL,
    intitule varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
    charge_hor int NOT NULL,
    coef double precision NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_module   PRIMARY KEY(code_mod) 
);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f291) is a SQL Fiddle.